# How do you convert a string to a Sympy expression without simplifying?

Tags: expression, sympy, simplification

I would like to use a function like [`sympify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=sympify#sympy.core.sympify) in order to convert the string `"c+1+1"` into a Sympy expression. However, I don't want it to simplify.

Right now, I do

```
from sympy import sympify
print(sympify("c+1+1")) # >> c + 2
```

The docs mentioned something about a `kernS` function that might simplify less, but it too does some simplification during the conversion:

```
from sympy.core.sympify import kernS
print(kernS("c+1+1")) # >> c + 2
```

What I would like to see back is `c+1+1`.

How do I turn a string into a Sympy expression without any simplifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I didn't read far enough in the docs.

The simplification can be stopped by setting the `evaluate` parameter to `False`, like so:

```
from sympy import sympify
print(sympify("c+1+1", evaluate=False)) # >> c + 1 + 1
```